# Dask read and partition dataframes with minimised peak memory usage

Tags: python, dask, lightgbm, dask-dataframe

I have a dataframe-esque dataset with the following structure, stored as a large number of csv files on disk:

```
[ target_col | timestamp_col | feature_1 | feature_2 | ... | feature_10000 ]
     int32         int64         float64    float64             float64
```

I would like to load this data into a dask dataframe, and split it into '`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`' style partitions where the train/test split is done on the `timestamp` column, and the `X` dataframe consists of all columns except the `target_col`. Naturally the `y` dataframe consists only of the `target_col`.

I'd also like to load this data into LightGBM datasets (although this is option).

Here's what I have so far:

```
with Client() as client:

    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH, 'data/*'))
    data = dd.read_csv(files[0:], dtype=col_dtypes)

    train = data.loc[data.timestamp_col < 1591010111]
    test = data.loc[data.timestamp_col > 1591010111]


    train = train.persist()
    x_cols = [c for c in train.columns if c not in ['target_col', 'timestamp_col']]

    X_train = train[x_cols]
    y_train = train['target_col']

    X_test = test[x_cols]
    y_test = test['target_col']

    print('Loading data into lightgbm.datasets...')
    train = lightgbm.Dataset(X_train.compute(), label=y_train.compute())
    
    test = lightgbm.Dataset(X_test.compute(), label=y_test.compute())
```

However, this has very high peak memory usage (far greater than the total size of the dataset) and I don't think I'm being maximally efficient with my usage of Dask here. Is there a better way to do this, where better is 'results in lower peak memory usage'?